# String functions in JPA in toplink (OAS 10.1.3.n)

Tags: substring, jpql, toplink, oas

I am trying the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SUBSTRING(c.name, 1, 1) FROM Country c
```

againest toplink that is bundled with Oracle Application Server 10.1.3.3 but I got an error saying:

`SUBSTRING token not recognized`

The question is, doesn't toplink 10.1.3.n support string functions? (I am sure it is JPA1.0, ain't it?
According to the v1.0 specs, SUBSTRING should be supported, so why toplink 10.1.3.n doesn't include it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Having functions within the select clause of a JPQL query was not supported by JPA 1.0.  Upgrading to TopLink 11.1.1.3.0 will provide JPA 2.0 functionality and support for functions in the JPQL select clause.

You can always issue native SQL or use a TopLink ReportQuery in TopLink 10.1.3.3

Comment: Yes, but not in the select clause.  Aggregate functions like SUM or AVG were the only functions allowed in the select clause in JPA 1.0